# Tracking list on elements on canvas (tkinter)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Is there a way to track elements properties in Tkinter canvas?

Specifically, I want to know if at a certain coordinates set I have already created an element or not.

I believe I can do this with tracking sets of elements in a dictinoary but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas has many methods for finding objects. You could, for example, call `find_closest` to find the element closest to the coordinate you are wanting to check. Then, for the element it finds, you can use the `coords` method to find out if all of the coordinates of the element are identical.

Comment: Thank you. I have ended up using a dictionary. I am using a tuple of the coordinates as the key.